# What is the PIE reconstruction for word-initial alpha with rough breathing?

Tags: historical-linguistics

What is the PIE reconstruction for word-initial alpha with rough breathing? My concern is the tendency (popularly) to mistake initial alpha as privative when it is not (e.g. hamartia): The easiest case, I suppose, is the rough breathing, in which case, am I right to imagine a reconstructed *ha? The question is relevant also, however, with any genuinely alpha-initial root.
Thank you.

Comment: Good question! But I'd recommend breaking the second part of the question ("what about word-initial alpha with smooth breathing?") off into its own question. I can give an answer to that too, but it's a separate thing.

Answer (score 6):

*Hamartía* "sin" is a hard example to use, because to my knowledge, *hamartánō* "to sin" has no known IE cognates. This means there's no way to check or confirm reconstructions, and it may not come from PIE at all. Instead, I'm going to use *háls* "salt".

In general, `/h/` in any Indo-European language (except Hittite!) has nothing to do with PIE laryngeals like `*h₁`. The laryngeals disappeared very early and are only visible by the effects they had on surrounding sounds.

In Ancient Greek in particular, `/h/` usually came from an earlier `*s` before a vowel. (Later, it disappeared when it wasn't at the start of a word; even later, it disappeared everywhere.) So the reconstructed PIE for "salt" was something like `*séh₂l-s`, as seen in Latin *sāl* and English *salt*.

This is also where the prefix *ha-* "together" came from: the PIE ancestor is reconstructed as `*sṃ`, as seen in Latin forms like *simplex* and *semel*. In Greek, `*ṃ` turned into *a*, and the `*s` turned into *h*, giving the *ha-* found in *Hāidēs*, *haploûs*, *hápas*, and so on.

P.S. Sometimes you won't see an `/h/` where you might expect one, as in *adelphós*, which has that same *ha-* prefix. This is due to "Grassmann's Law": if you have two or more aspirated consonants in a word, all but the last one lose their aspiration. This is why you see ***h***éksō alongside *ék**h**ō*: in the future tense, the *khs* simplifies into *k*, which allows the original *h* at the beginning to show through.